# Can't set breakpoint in .aspx file (no code behind)

Tags: c#, asp.net, debugging, breakpoints

I've got a single page, `.aspx`, file that contains some JavaScript code and some C# code. There is no code-behind file. The C# code is:

```
<script language="c#" runat="server">

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;
    string auth = Request.Headers["Authorization"];
    label1.InnerText = auth; 
    return;
}

</script>
```

I have created a web page referencing a local website under IIS. I am running this in Visual Studio 2017 with administrator privileges. Nevertheless, I cannot set a breakpoint within the C# code. I just get the following notice

> A breakpoint could not be inserted at this location."

Is there some restriction in setting a breakpoint is code that does not exist in a separate code-behind file?

Comment: Did you add `AutoEventWireup` attribute `true` to @Page directive? For example, `<% @Page AutoEventWireup="true" ... %>`. Also right click and click on `Clean Solution`.

Comment: Add `Debug="true"` in `<%@ Page` directive.

Comment: I used to be able to set breakpoints in the embedded server-side code of my *.ascx/*.aspx files. But the quote on @Adriani6's answer implies that newer Visual Studio versions may no longer support this. Which is unfortunate, as I'd like to debug some complex rendering logic in old code.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do that. In my experience, the ability to set break point is not stable. When VS disallows that, here is something you can try to enable it:

1. Move the C# Script section to the top (when you have lots of html above c#)
2. Refresh the aspx page in browser, then try set the break point again.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

That's because the page gets rendered when its loaded so that's not compiled code and thus you can't set a breakpoint since the compiler isn't aware of it.

Here's a quote from [MSDN Page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178135.aspx):

> Embedded code blocks are supported in ASP.NET Web Forms pages
>   primarily to preserve backward compatibility with older ASP
>   technology. In general, using embedded code blocks for complex
>   programming logic is not a best practice, because when the code is
>   mixed on the page with markup, it can be difficult to debug and
>   maintain. In addition, because the code is executed only during the
>   page's render phase, you have substantially less flexibility than with
>   code-behind or script-block code in scoping your code to the
>   appropriate stage of page processing.

Comment: i used to debug code in aspx page for years, then suddenly stop working. So IMHO your answer is not correct. I mean, the Micorsoft comment is right, it's not a good practice, definetly a bad idea to put here complex logic. But this don't  mean you can't debug, quite opposite, it tells debug is difficult (then it's possibile, but difficult due to mixed nature of the code here).